# Gradient of metric product

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

I am learning new concept of differential geometry and tensorial calculus. In an exercise, I came in a step where I should simplify the relation
                         $∇g(X,Y)=?$
Where $X$ and $Y$ are tangent vectors on a manifold $M$ and $g$ is the metric over $M$.
I don't know if I can relies the above quantity with other quantites like covariant derivative of $X$ over $Y$? or if there is a rool to find the gradient of the metric. 
In the exercise the vector $X=∇f$ where $f$ is a function defined on $M$, but I want to know the general case.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You wrote gradient, but context suggests this is covariant derivative, not gradient.